# Limits of the type $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t F(u,t) du$

Tags: calculus, limits

How does one perform a limit of an integral when the limiting variable is involved in the integrand and the integration limit? To be concrete, the problem is to determine
$$
L = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t F(u,t) du,
$$
where $F(u,t)$ is some continuous function of both $u$ and $t$ (the limiting variable). Although the limit when $F$ is independent of $t$ -- $ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t F(u) du$ -- is zero by the definition, the limit where $F$ depends on $t$ is not necessarily zero.

In general, the integral is difficult to evaluate in closed form, so
my current approach has been to Taylor expand $F$ about $u=0$, evaluate the integral term by term, and then take the limit, as in
$$
L = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t\big(F(0,t) + u F_u(0,t) + \dots \big) du.
$$
For example, if $F(u,t) = \frac{1}{t}e^{-a u/t},$ the limit is
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a u)^n}{t^{n+1} n!} du = - \frac{1}{a}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a )^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{a}\Big(1 - e^{-a}\Big),
$$
but for complicated $F$ this can be tedious. Is there a more intuitive way to solve such limits?

Comment: You could write that for $t\leqslant 1$,
$$ \int_0^t F(u,t)du=\int_0^1 \varphi_t(u)du $$
where $\varphi_t(u):=F(u,t)\chi_{\{u\leqslant t\}}$ and use the dominated convergence theorem. In particular, if $F$ is bounded, then we can use the dominated convegence theorem so that $L=0$. If $F$ is not bounded, I think we can't do without a case by case study.

Comment: Often (but not always) one can repeatedly integrate by parts to produce the asymptotic series in powers of $t$